# Knockout Visible Binding Style Display Inline not working

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I am using the `visible` binding in knockout. I want to set the `h3` html element to `display:inline`.  However, after the binding occurs the inline css `display: inline` is cleared and it reverts back. When I do not use the `visible` binding then I don't have the issue.

```
<div style='display: inline'>
    <label style='display: inline'>Product Total</label>
</div>
<div style='display: inline'>
    <h3 style='display: inline' data-bind='visible: Total() > 3, text: Total'></h3>
</div>
```

Enter a value above 3 to reproduce the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryandxavier/ung4z/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `visible` binding togles the visibility of the element between `""` and `"none"`, so you need to create a custom binding which support the the `inline` display:

Based on the visible [source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/visible.js) (you can further extend this passing in the desiered display value as a parameter):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['visibleInline'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var isCurrentlyVisible = !(element.style.display == "none");
        if (value && !isCurrentlyVisible)
            element.style.display = "inline";
        else if ((!value) && isCurrentlyVisible)
            element.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

And use in the your html:

```
<h3 style='display: inline' data-bind='visibleInline: Total() > 3, text: Total'></h3>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bVMJ/).

Or as an alternative solution your can use the container-less syntax and don't put the binding on your `h3` and use `if` instead of `visible`:

```
<h3 style='display: inline'>
    <!-- ko if: Total() > 3 -->
        <!-- ko text: Total --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</h3>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyUVM/).

Comment: The thought to just go look at the source code never crossed my mind.  I will definitely be doing that in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
data-bind="style: { display: yesOrNo() ? 'inline' : 'none' }"
```